# Textbox validation using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate `textbox` within my c# form so I made this method to do check below

1. Only number are allowed.
2. Only a-z are allowed.
3. Replacing the more than withe spaces with one space and return the string.

Problem the only number are allowed always get me the error message even if there is no a-z.

Finally any suggestion or improvement to below code ?

I have made some update now please if their is any suggestion or improvement or any checks usual standard I have missed

**Edit on 20/3/2016 1:12 PM GMT**

GMT Time [now](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=time+now+GMT) :D

```
                public void input_validation()
    {
        string num_regex = @"^[0-9]*$";         //only digits allowed in this textbox
        string word_regex = @"[a-zA-Z]+";       //only a-z allowed in this textbox
        string Multi_spaces = @"\s+|\s{2,}";   //more than on white spaces

        Regex Nregex = new Regex(num_regex);
        Regex Wregex = new Regex(word_regex);
        Regex Mregex = new Regex(Multi_spaces);

        //To check all empty textbox within the groupbox
        foreach (var emptytxtbox in GB_CUST_INFO.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emptytxtbox.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Information are no allowed\n","Missing Information",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                emptytxtbox.BackColor = Color.Red;
                return; //to stop the check on first empty textbox 
            }
            else
            {
                emptytxtbox.BackColor = Color.White; //to rest the color of missed info at pervious check
            }

            if (Mregex.IsMatch(emptytxtbox.Text))
            {
              //just replacing the more than one white spaces with one white space and retrun to its textbox
                emptytxtbox.Text = Mregex.Replace(emptytxtbox.Text," ");
            }
        }

        if (!Nregex.IsMatch(TB_CUST_PHONE1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Only Number are allowed for phone number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        else if (!Nregex.IsMatch(TB_CUST_PHONE2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Only Number are allowed for mobile number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        //else if (Mregex.IsMatch(TB_CUST_NAME.Text))
        //{   //just replacing the more than one white spaces with one white space and retrun to its textbox
        //    TB_CUST_NAME.Text = Mregex.Replace(TB_CUST_NAME.Text, " ");
        //}
        /*else if (Wregex.IsMatch(TB_CUST_NAME.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Only a-z are allowed");
        }*/
        else { cust_data_insert(); }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting on numbers ? Are you applying all three conditions on same `textbox` ?

Comment: I mean it always true.. I get the messagebox.show i write no matter what the input within the textbox 4656 or 456asd it always true

Comment: well, lets begin with this. `if (regex1.IsMatch(TB_CUST_PHONE1.Text))` causes an error to be thrown if the regex is matched--in other words, if it looks like a phone number. Your logic is inverted. Moreover, "only number are allowed" and "only a-z are allowed" are logically impossible to combine, so your problem statement makes no sense.

Comment: Couldn't you combine both statements like `[\da-zA-Z]+` ?

Comment: @zeromus there ! I justed miss it while I am testing it when I put else if (!regex3.IsMatch(TB_CUST_PHONE1.Text)) I got the error in both cases.. I had updated my code now

Comment: @Jan No I cant cause thats not applicable to all textbox some are only numbers and other only a-z

Comment: it sounds like you want
if(is_phone_number) { pass }
else if(is_all_letters) { pass }
else { error! is not phone number or letters! }

Comment: I want to pass only number the minimum check for not formatted number

Comment: What tech stack are you using? ASP.NET/MVC? Winforms? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, to match numbers in your textbox you should use this :

```
string num_regex = @"^[0-9]*$";
```

Comment: I have test it on this site and that's will catch nothing  http://www.regexr.com/ since the ^ mean NOT in 0-9 and * mean zero or more am I right ?

Comment: `^` is the begining of the string and `$` is the end. Your textbox can contains multiple lines ?

Answer (score 0):

To test for only numbers in your TextBox try the following regex:

```
string num_only_regex = @"[0-9]+$";
```

I've tested it myself an it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var text = "abc12-   443";
var sanitizedText = string.Empty;

var result = Regex.Match(text, @"^[a-z0-9\s]+$",
             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (result.Success)
{
    sanitizedText = Regex.Replace(result.Value, "[ ]+", " ");
    Console.WriteLine(sanitizedText);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: ({0})", text);
}
```

This should print:

```
abc12 443   #for abc12   443
Invalid input: (abc12-   443)     #for abc12- 443
```

See [Demo](http://goo.gl/df63he) here

Comment: There are so many variables (unknowns) so getting exactly what's wrong is difficult as complete code is not available. However, my snippet above should solve your original question that is accepting only alpha numeric and one space. See link posted in my answer.